# How can I find files that are nested too deep?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, directory

I have a parent folder that contains inside it multiple folders named Project-* (folders are numbered so Project-1, Project-15, Project-253 etc). Inside of each of those folders is a zip file, always the same name 'project.zip'. This means that when the folder structure is correct it should ALWAYS be TopFolder\Project-*\project.zip.

I am trying to write a program that looks at each Project-* folder to see if the project.zip file is nested inside another folder (example: Project-*\newfolder\project.zip)

I have some code that looks for folders called Project-* and lists them if they have subdirectories, but it seems to consider my project.zip files as folders so it is showing EVERYthing as having subdirectories.

```
 DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(txtbxOldFolder.Text);
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = directory.GetDirectories("*Project-*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


            //finds folders nested in the folder
            var query = from folder in folders
                        where folder.GetFileSystemInfos().Length > 0 
                        select folder.FullName.ToString();
            foreach (string str in query)
            {
                //this adds the path of any Project-* folder with subdirectories
                listNestedFolder.Add(str);
            }
```

As mentioned the above code does find any Project-* folder with subdirectories, however it also finds any that are Project-*\project.zip. How can I get it to stop identifying the zip file as a directory?

Comment: Worth noting, you should use GetDirectories (like the answers below), but if you wanted to exclude Zips from your list you could use `&& (folder.Attributes & System.IO.FileAttributes.Archive) == 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetFileSystemInfos()` returns both files and folders.
You probably want to call `GetDirectories()`.

For better performance, you can write `where folder.EnumerateDirectories().Any()`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this logic to search for nested files or any other differences in subdirectories structure:

```
        string topfolder = @"c:\temp\utils\";
        string filename = "project.zip";

        foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(topfolder, "Project-*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
            if (files.Count() > 1)
            #region if directory contains extra (unexpected) files
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Directory {0} contains {1} files", dir, files.Count()));
            }
            #endregion if directory contains extra (unexpected) files

            if (!files.Contains(filename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File is not found in {0}", dir));

                #region Searching for the file in depth

                files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                if (files.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The file has been found too deep:");
                    foreach (string s in files)
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                }

                #endregion Searching for the file in depth
            }

            #region Searching for extra (unexpected) subdirectories

            int dircount = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
            if (dircount > 0)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Directory {0} contains {1} subdirectories", dir, dircount));

            #endregion Searching for extra (unexpected) subdirectories
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```